# Issue w/ternary operator in click function

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

I have a form that switches between a "Log In" and "Recover Password" form with the click of "a.flipLink". The h2 is initially set to have the text "Log In" I want to change it to "Recover" on the first click of "a.flipLink" and back to "Log In" on the second click, so the appropriate title is shown with its related form. This seems like it should work, and it changes on the first click but does not change back to "Log In" on the second click.

```
$('.flipLink').click(function(e){
    formContainer.toggleClass('flipped');
    $('h2#LogIn').text($('#LogIn').text() == 'Log In' ? 'Recover Password' : 'Log In');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Id rather not define a click handler for each 'a.flipLink' - they do have individual ID's though. To re-iterate, H2 is initially "Log In" clicking "a.flipLink" should change it to "Recover Password" (can do), then clicking it again should change it back to "Log In" basically should just toggle text between "Log In" and "Recover Password"
thx

this however works:

```
if ($('h2#LogIn').text() == "Log In")
   $('h2#LogIn').text('Recover Password')
 else
   $('h2#LogIn').text('Log In');
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/fBSX7/

Comment: It only fires the first time, I had to go this route:
if ($('h2#LogIn').text() == "Log In")
     $('h2#LogIn').text('Recover Password')
     else
     $('h2#LogIn').text('Log In');

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: It fires all the time for me in his fiddle.

Comment: nope, link w/ '.flipLink' is always present

Comment: What give you console.log($('#LogIn').text()) inside click handler on second click?

Comment: you're question and you're code don't match.  you're link shows `$('h2#LogIn').text($('#LogIn').text() == 'Recover Password' ? 'Log In' : 'Recover Password');`  -- it's backwards.   makes me wonder what else is off.

Comment: console.log($('#LogIn').text()) always shows "Log In"

Comment: See jbabey's answer. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @jbaby, got it thanks for the help. If you want a star or check or whatever it is, please post as answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: can we get some question editing? The question doesn't match the answer at all now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two elements on your page with the same ID:

```
<a id="LogIn" href="LogIn.php" target="_self">Log In</a></p>
...
<h2 id="LogIn" class="center">Log In</h2>
```

Change the `h2` id to something unique, change the respective jquery selectors, and it will work fine.